# How to call web service method from Web content display in Liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I am creating a page using Liferay 6.2 where i need to display html contents sent as response from web service method. After seeing the customization and features available in web content display, i am planning to use them. As i am new to VM and FTL, i am not sure how to call web service method from web content display content. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom velocity tool as explained in [this post](http://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/custom-velocity-tools-and-liferay-6-0).